# Range query on kyoto cabinet using Java API

Tags: key-value-store, kyotocabinet

I am interested in using `kyotocabinet` key-value store and I want to preform a range query preferably with a bulk interface (returning byte array). I checked `kyotocabinet`s Java API and I couldn't find any particular method to do this. As range queries are very common for key-value stores, I was wondering if anybody has experience in doing range queries over `kyotocabinet`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?